# wkhtmltoimage - sometimes get entire page, sometimes not

Tags: javascript, php, shell, command, wkhtmltoimage

```
$command = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage --quality 70 --crop-w 800 --crop-x 50 --javascript-delay 900 --height 800";
```

Hello, i've finished simple script to convert any url to jpg via `wkhtmltoimage` im using this for facebook, but sometimes it works sometimes not 
with default setting
`--javascript-delay 200`  screenshot was empty, with `900ms` delay it's working ok. but sometimes one or more image is missing, i've tried to disable javascript, or change wait time to even 2s but sometimes work, sometimes not.
I need simple solution to make screenshot from facebook url, but i dont want use third parties services. There is any setting to avoid this issue ? and retry when image was not saved ? Because sometimes also image is not saved, and this is too often to accept this.

Comment: i would use an event instead of a timer, if possible. the  other option is to try to examine the image to see if it's incomplete and should be "retaken".

Comment: i need fast response, as fast as possible, in this way it takes too long.

Comment: the fastest way is by using events since they let you know exactly when something is done. now, if your tools provide such events, i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Option `--disable-smart-width` worked for me. I had a similar issue capturing screenshots from some sites that did not render completely.

Check what the guy in this GitHub issue did https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2408.

Unlike him, I did not have to disable javascript and I also did not have to add a delay.